# Jquery script for image scrolling in div not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am merely looking for some help as a newbie learning webdesign, please understand I am still in the very early stages of learning when answering my question.

I have the following:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery/css/smoothDivScroll.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="jquery/js/jquery.smoothdivscroll-1.3-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery/js/jquery.kinetic.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
#makeMeScrollable div.scrollableArea *
{
    position: relative;
    display: block
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    /* If you don't want the images in the scroller to be selectable, try the following
        block of code. It's just a nice feature that prevent the images from
        accidentally becoming selected/inverted when the user interacts with the scroller. */
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({
            mousewheelScrolling: "allDirections",
            manualContinuousScrolling: true,
            autoScrollingMode: "onStart"
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="makeMeScrollable">
        <img src="images/demo/field.jpg" alt="Field" id="field" />
        <img src="images/demo/gnome.jpg" alt="Gnome" id="gnome" />
        <img src="images/demo/pencils.jpg" alt="Pencils" id="pencils" />
        <img src="images/demo/golf.jpg" alt="Golf" id="golf" />
        <img src="images/demo/river.jpg" alt="River" id="river" />
        <img src="images/demo/train.jpg" alt="Train" id="train" />
        <img src="images/demo/leaf.jpg" alt="Leaf" id="leaf" />
        <img src="images/demo/dog.jpg" alt="Dog" id="dog" />
    </div>
```

The plugin is  from [this website](http://smoothdivscroll.com/)

My problem is when I upload my page to server and view it, I am clearly doing something wrong, since instead of images actually scrolling in div, all 5 images are just displayed in a row.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like your missing this javascript

```
<script src="js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

as mentioned here http://smoothdivscroll.com/dependencies.html

smoothDivScroll wont work until and unless you import **mousewheel.min.js**